# Running BeforeTestRun/AfterTestRun once on Specflow Runner

Tags: specflow, specrun

Does anyone have successfully setup a beforetestrun/aftertestrun hook when using Specflow runner on multithread using AppDomain
I saw some answer from this thread - [Run BeforeTestRun and AfterTestRun only once using specflow with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62426296/run-beforetestrun-and-aftertestrun-only-once-using-specflow-with-selenium)

Unfortunately, I'm having difficulty to set this up as we need it to configure our TestRail integration.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible - you have to use a kernel-based lock (the following constructor is the one to use):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Semaphore__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_String_System_Boolean__

The flow:

1. Create a named instance of Semaphore
2. The thread where createdNew == true is the first thread that entered the code - execute test run init code here
3. For other threads use method 'WaitOne' with a proper timeout

Best regards,
PM